# .net Application is slow on publish

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, administrator

I've made a sqlite DB application (.net Winforms) which is working fine. When I'm debuging the application in VS 2010 it starts up in 2-3 seconds. Also when i copy it to my desktop it is starting in this time. But when I'm making a setup which is installing to Program Files or Program Files (x86) it takes up to 10 minutes to start my application. Also when I start it from C:\ root. When I run it as administrator, or i provide a manifest to force administrator it takes 2-3 seconds.

On start up, i check with a few if File.Exists statements, if all dll's and files are in my folder.

I also have a log writer, which is creating a log file in AppData folder.
So i don't think I have any code part where administator rights were required.

Probably it could be the "SQLite.Interop.dll" but I'm not sure about this.

Hope someone could help me. If the are other questions or code is needed please ask.

Thanks
Martin

## EDIT

Tried the application on a networkdrive, tooks 5 seconds to start without administrator.

I found out, that if i delete the language.sqlite file from my application folder, my application says language file missing. But when i reinsert the file, it keeps loading and loading.

Next test: I have added ALL System Dll's that I'm using in my application.

http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150611/3suqkzeq.png
(I can't post imags..)

This way it is working BUT only on the VM on my PC it isn't...

Comment: Have you used a profiler at all to measure where the time is being spent?

Comment: Network drive maybe? Antivirus maybe?

Comment: I've tried Windbg and Ollydbg, wasn't able to find something (never used before). The application is slow on local drive, network drive I didn't tried. Also the antivirus is not possible, because I tried it also on a VM without AV.